# Changing status code from proxied backend server with nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, http-status-code

I am proxying some paths to another server. That server responds with 302 Moved Temporarily. I need to change that particular status code to 200 OK.  Otherwise I can pass response through as-is and other status codes should pass without changes.

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://some.server/api;
}
```

Reason for status code mangling is IE that wont work with 302 status code in this request when using Ajax.

Comment: But 200 should give some result content, I guess. How should nginx get it?

Comment: 200 with empty content or fixed content (specified in nginx configuration) or 204 No Content are also suitable responses in my case.

Comment: Well, then you need `error_page` and `proxy_intercept_errors`